# How do I return the record with the earliest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to return the first record for each distinct student ID.  In my sample code, I have one record with two incidents on the same date, and another student with multiple incidents on different dates.

I would need to select the earliest date, and if more than one happened on the same date, then the earliest incident ID as the next criteria.  What's a good way to do this?

I have about 35 columns in this data set, but only included the first 5 below for brevity.

**Data:**

[image: Picture of data]

**Desired Results:**

[image: Picture of desired results]

The sample code is below.

```
  CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
  StudentID float,
  SchoolID float,
  StudentNameFull nvarchar(255),
  IncidentID float,
  IncidentDate date
  )

  INSERT INTO #TEMP (StudentID, SchoolID, StudentNameFull, IncidentID, IncidentDate)
  VALUES 
  (1111111, 406, 'Smith,John', 123321, '20170501'),
  (1111111, 406, 'Smith,John', 123322, '20170501'),
  (2222222, 406, 'Jones,Tim',  654789, '20170501'),
  (2222222, 406, 'Jones,Tim',  659872, '20170503'),
  (2222222, 406, 'Jones,Tim',  478978, '20170508')

  SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StudentId order by IncidentDate, IncidentID) as seqnum 
      from #TEMP t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This interprets "easiest incident" as "incidentId with the smallest value".

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, did you mean "earliest incident"?

Comment: I prefer to do these things with `DENSE_RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`. If there is a tie, ROW_NUMBER will only select one record, while DENSE_RANK would select both (or more). Even in cases like this, where ties probably aren't to be expected, I want to know if they *do* occur.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger, would the syntax be similar?  Just replace Row_Number with Dense_Rank?

Comment: @JM1, Yes, syntax is the same as `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, when I run DENSE_RANK in my production environment, it shows I have more records than ROW_NUMBER.  It has duplicate student ID's in the result.  Why would this be?

Comment: @JM1 the combination of StudentID, IncidentDate and IncidentID is not unique. Like I said, ROW_NUMBER forces uniqueness

Comment: I see you mentioned that already, I didn't catch it. Thanks @HoneyBadger,

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **With Ties** clause in concert with **Row_Number()**

```
  SELECT Top 1 with Ties * 
  FROM #TEMP
  Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By StudentID Order by IncidentDate,IncidentID )
```

Comment: You forgot to order also by the `IncidentId` ... check the data closely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank for the catch

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Not new.  I just like this approach becase there is no extra field

Comment: I am new to keyword `With Ties`.. Thanx

Comment: @ShakeerMirza That is why I love SO.  I learn something new every day.  That's the fun part

Comment: +1 This is actually genius, I happen to hate the `WHERE`-clause approach for exactly the same reason, the resulting extra column. Thanks for this refreshingly easy approach! As you said, you learn something new every day :)